# Function to redefine functions so that they operate with a modified argument

Tags: expl3

I need to locally redefine some commands taking one argument, so that they are executed with the argument modified by the addition of a prefix. For instance,
I need to locally redefine `\label` so that `\label{a}` actually acts like `\label{prefix:a}` and similarly to redefine `\ref` so that `\ref{a}` actually acts like `\ref{prefix:a}`.

This is because I need to import into a document many pieces of other documents where labels were defined 'in isolation', so now in the master documents there may be label clashes.

To give you a better idea. I have something like

```
\begin{document}
  <stuff here>
  \Read{a}
  \Read{b}
  ...
  \Read{z}
  <stuff here>
\end{document}
```

where `\Read` is a wrapper around `\input` and `a.tex`, `b.tex` ecc. are sections of other documents written in isolation. As a consequence `a.tex` may contain `\label{zero}` and `\ref{zero}` while `b.tex` may also contain `\label{zero}` and `\ref{zero}`.

Hence I would like to assure that `\Read` before doing the input, opens a group and locally redefines `\label`, `\ref`, etc. so that the arguments are managed with a prefix. When I do `\label{zero}` in `a.tex` the effect is the same as doing `\label{a:zero}`, and so on.

To do this efficiently, I would like to have a macro `\__xxx_localize_func_onearg:nN` to be used e.g. as `\__xxx_localize_func_onearg:nN{a}{\label}` to locally modify `\label`.
Eventually, I would like to wrap everything into a `\__xxx_localize_func_onearg:nn`, so that I can say `\__xxx_localize_func_onearg:nn{a}{\label,\ref,\pageref,\eqref}` and have all the commands passed as the second argument locally modified at once.

How could I do it with `expl3`? I know that `expl3` offers many ways to control expansion which is certainly needed to

- save the current code stored in #2 into some other macro. E.g. if #2 is `\label`, to save the code of `\label` in `\saved_label`
- redefine #2 to call the saved code with the altered argument. E.g. if #2 is `\label`, and #1 is `a` redefine `\label` to do `\saved_label{a:#1}`

Unfortunately, I cannot really catch from the manual how to use the functions of the `l3expan` package for the task, since I cannot find many examples of use.

So far I have this, where I am not still dealing with the first argument

```
\cs_new:Nn \__xxx_localize_funcs_onearg:n
  {
    \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__xxx_localize_func_onearg:N
  }

\cs_new:Nn \__xxx_localize_func_onearg:N
  {
    % Identify name to save the function
    %\tl_show:n {*#1*}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \cs_to_str:N #1 } 
    %\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
    % Save the function
    \cs_set_eq:cN { __xxx_saved_\l_tmpa_tl :n } #1
    \cs_show:c { __bookfmt_saved_\l_tmpa_tl :n }
    % Locally redefine the function to use the saved one
    % What should I put here?????
  }
```

Comment: Not `expl3` but for *simple* applications `\let\oldlabel\label \def\label#1{\oldlabel{prefix:#1}}` would work.

Comment: Yes, for a single one it is easy. The whole point is that I want to have a function doing it: `\label` must be something that I can pass as a parameter, because I do not know how many of those I might need to redefine, so I want to be able to do the redefinition through a function.

Answer (score 1):

Approach using `xpatch`. It only changes the first appearance of `#1` in the macro's definition, though.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand\applyprefixtocmd{}
\protected\edef\applyprefixtocmd#1#2%
  {%
    \noexpand\xpatchcmd{#1}{\string#1}{#2\string#1}{}
      {%
        \noexpand\GenericError{}
          {%
            Prefixing the first argument of \noexpand\string#1\noexpand\space
            didn't work%
          }
          {Now you're screwed.}{}%
      }%
  }
\newcommand\test[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\applyprefixtocmd\test{prefix:}
\test{foo}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Adding a macro to process a list of macros:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand\applyprefixtocmd{}
\protected\edef\applyprefixtocmd#1#2%
  {%
    \noexpand\xpatchcmd{#1}{\string#1}{#2\string#1}{}
      {%
        \noexpand\GenericError{}
          {%
            Prefixing the first argument of \noexpand\string#1\noexpand\space
            didn't work%
          }
          {Now you're screwed.}{}%
      }%
  }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \applyprefixtocmdlist { m m }
  {
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 } { \applyprefixtocmd { ##1 } { #1 } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\testA[1]{#1}
\newcommand\testB[1]{#1}
\newcommand\testC[1]{#1}
\newcommand\testD[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\applyprefixtocmdlist{prefix:}{\testA,\testB,\testC,\testD}
\testA{foo}\par
\testB{foo}\par
\testC{foo}\par
\testD{foo}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Variant that patches every occurrence of `#1` to include the prefix, it always uses `@` as a letter (cleaned up, thanks to @egreg).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_callegar_atsave_int
\NewDocumentCommand \applyprefixtocmd { m m }
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_callegar_atsave_int { \char_value_catcode:n { `\@ } }
    \makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd* { #1 } { ##1 } { #2 ##1 } {} {}
    \char_set_catcode:nn { `\@ } { \l_callegar_atsave_int }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \applyprefixtocmdlist { m m }
  {
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 } { \applyprefixtocmd { ##1 } { #1 } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\newcommand\testA[1]{#1 and \@firstofone{#1}}
\newcommand\testB[1]{#1}
\newcommand\testC[1]{#1}
\newcommand\testD[1]{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\applyprefixtocmdlist{prefix:}{\testA,\testB,\testC,\testD}
\testA{foo}\par
\testB{foo}\par
\testC{foo}\par
\testD{foo}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution that will only work if we can use `\let` safely and only lets you modify the first argument.

For convenience the syntax is `\redefwithprefix{<prefix>}{<command>}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\redefwithprefix}{}
%{<prefix>}{<cmd>}
\protected\def\redefwithprefix#1#2{%
  \expandafter\let\csname rdp@old@\string#2\endcsname#2
  \def#2##1{\csname rdp@old@\string#2\endcsname{#1:##1}}}

\def\foo#1{X#1Y}

\begin{document}
\foo{A}

\redefwithprefix{a}{\foo}
\foo{B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, but is there any way to modify the `\def#2##1 ...` so that the ` \csname rdp@old@\string#2\endcsname` is expanded when doing the definition?

Comment: @Callegar `\edef#2##1{\unexpanded\expandafter{\csname rdp@old@\string#2\endcsname}{#1:##1}}`

Comment: Or `\expandafter\def\expandafter#2\expandafter##\expandafter1\expandafter{\csname rdp@old@\string#2\endcsname{#1:##1}}`.

Comment: @moewe the `\edef` variant seems way clearer, imho.

Comment: @Skillmon Agreed and it is even clearer when one uses the `etoolbox` macro `\expandonce` instead of `\unexpanded\expandafter`. But I've always wondered how to get the expansion with `\def` right, so I thought I might as well try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
\cs_new:Nn \__bookfmt_localize_funcs_onearg:n
  {
    \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__bookfmt_localize_func_onearg:N
  }

\cs_new:Nn \__bookfmt_localize_func_onearg:N
  {
    % Identify name to save the function
    \exp_args:NNo \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \csname __bookfmt_saved_\cs_to_str:N #1 \endcsname}
    \exp_args:Noo \__bookfmt_localize_func_onearg_aux:nNN {\l_bookfmt_codice_tl}{\l_tmpa_tl}{#1}
  }

\cs_new:Nn \__bookfmt_localize_func_onearg_aux:nNN
  {
    % Save the function
    \cs_set_eq:NN #2 #3
    % Locally redefine the function to use the saved one
    \cs_set:Npn #3 ##1 {#2 { #1:##1 }  }
  }
```

So I can do `\__bookfmt_localize_funcs_onearg:n {\label, \ref, \pageref, \eqref}`. Note that there is no first argument for the prefix, which is assumed to be stored into `\l_bookfmt_codice_tl`

Still it does not seem quite elegant to me. Any way to remove the auxiliary function?